# Disadvantages of wire cut cnc edm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, cnc, cutting, lathe

Before purchasing **Wire cut cnc edm** I just wants to know about disadvantages of it over using mechanical lathe machine.

Comment: Surely the disadvantages will be particular to the use or parts you wish to make? Others making different things may not see or suffer the same disadvantages : for them they may be conveniences. You may wish to elaborate what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Wire EDM and a lathe aren't really directly comparable. Wire EDM is typically used for profile cutting of very hard materials such as hardened tool steel with good dimensional accuracy and may also be useful for producing very small holes or slots.

As a result it tends to be quite a specialist process and compared to conventional machining processes on materials with good machinability it will tend to have a low rate of material removal and may be less versatile.

I'm tempted to suggest that if you don't already know *why* you need an EDM machine you probably don't need one.